# Break into debugger on numpy exception in PTVS

Tags: python, numpy, ptvs

I'm using PTVS to debug some code I've written. I'd like to get it to break into the debugger whenever a numpy exception is raised. Currently, it only breaks into the debugger when a standard Python exception is raised; whenever a numpy exception is raised, all I get is a traceback print out.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own exception types in the Exceptions dialog (in Debug -> Exceptions), and then check them to have it break on them.